# Q/promises - Specifying 'this' when using fapply

Tags: this, q

I think I might be missing something obvious here, but if I have an object with a couple of functions, such as:

```
myFunctions = {
    getLastName: function() { return " Bloggs"; },
    getName: function(prefix) { return prefix + this.getLastName(); }
};
```

... how can I ensure 'this' is referencing the object in getName() when I call it with promise syntax, i.e:

```
q.fapply(myFunctions.getName, ['Mr.'])
    .then(function(fullName) {
        ...
    });
```

Currently, 'this' is just global scope when called via q.fapply()

Answer (score 0):

Use `Q.post` instead,

```
var myFunctions = {
    getLastName: function() { return " Bloggs"; },
    getName: function(prefix) { return prefix + this.getLastName(); }
};

Q.post(myFunctions, 'getName', ['Mr.'])
  .then(function(fullName) {
      alert(fullName);
  });
```